# WPF ComboBox Bind SQL with selectedValue as in database

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two tables.
Table1 linked with Table2 via Table2ID.

I need to have a combobox to load all data in Table2 and show the initial selected as shown in Table1.

The below code can only load all data from Table2, but not able to show the selected as shown in Table1

Can any one help me?
Thanks.

[image]
In this image, the combobox should show "Siong Wan Trading" when the windows first load.

```
Table1
ID  Name    Table2ID
1   Hello   1
2   World   1
3   User    2

Table2
ID  Name
1   ABC
2   DEF

private DataSet getData()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("usp_getalldata", conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "DATA");
            return ds;
        }
public Details()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataSet ds = getData();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        this.combobox.ItemsSource = ((IListSource)dt).GetList();
        this.combobox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        this.combobox.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    this.combobox.SelectedValue = Table2ID;
```

Used the above and it worked.
Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You should an [`ObjectDataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.aspx) as the `ItemsSource` of your `ComboBox` in your XAML.

Here's an example how to use it.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyDataSource" ObjectType="{x:Type my:StaticDataSource}" MethodName="GetMyData"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

...

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyDataSource}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Table2ID}"/>
```

Your `StaticDataSource` class looks like this:

```
public class MyDataSource
{
    private static IEnumerable<Table2> myData;

    public MyDataSource(IEnumerable<Table2> data)
    {
        myData = data;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Table2> GetMyData()
    {
        return myData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Guillaume, I am able to show the Table2 records in the combobox, but I need the comboxbox initial selected value shown as in Table1's Table2ID.

Comment: You need to bind the `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to the corresponding property of your `Table1` object. There's no such thing in your code in your question.